# Inexplicable EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to build a class for handling all sqlite3 work and I've encountered an EXC_BAD_ACCESS which I just can't explain. I am new to Objective-C development and memory management in general so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

When initializing the class I get the path to the database file and keep it around:

```
NSArray * documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
databasePath = [[[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sql"] retain];
```

Then I try to use it and it crashes on me:

```
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) { // crashes
```

The odd thing is that the exact same line in a different function works perfectly. I tried adding the variable initialization to above the line, but to no avail:

```
NSArray * documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
databasePath = [[[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sql"] retain];

if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) { // crashes
```

In both cases the retain count is 2.

However, putting any form of static text in there works fine:

```
databasePath = @"I have a balloon";
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) { // fine
// or
if (sqlite3_open([@"APPLES!" UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) { // fine
```

A little more experimentation revealed that it was the *UTF8String* function that was crashing, but I don't understand why.

Edit: Even more experimentation resulted in me being able to call the *UTF8String* function but not even use the results:

```
const char * test = [databasePath UTF8String];
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:test]); // fine
if (sqlite3_open(test, &database) == SQLITE_OK) { // fails
```

Edit: Messed around even more and discovered that the problem was in a parameter that I was passing to the function. I had breakpoints all over the place so I was 100% sure that the point it fails is at the line I specified, a line which doesn't use the passed variable, but somehow it caused everything to fail. Sometimes. I have no idea how it went wrong, but I rewrote the entire thing, changed my function call and now it works.

Thanks to all who answered.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but if documentPaths is nil, you're calling sqlite3_open with a null first argument.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the contents of the `databasePath` variable before the open call is made? Add an `NSLog` statement, or use the debugger, to find its value – it could be either `NULL`, which may not be handled by the `sqlite3_open` function, or it could even be that the crash is because the path is valid, and the database it points to is corrupt.

Comment: It's full of contents. I tested the _UTF8String_ function and got results out of that too, but once I try passing anything to the sqlite3 function it crashes.

Comment: And what is the contents…? If you pass it as a constant string, does it still crash?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the database variable is not declared properly. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the path to the database.

Did you declare database like this?:

```
sqlite3 *database;
```

Comment: Yeah, right above the line that crashes. I didn't think to add it since I deduced that the string was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are chasing the wrong problem.  You haven't shown a crash dump but claim that opening "APPLES!" is 'fine' which sounds odd - surely you don't have a database with that name?

Are you sure you don't have a bad database file lying around - ie, the database file you are trying to open is corrupted in some way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to post the crash log, your crash makes no sense.  The code you posted should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try a copy instead of a retain on the variable - it'll make an immutable copy of the string so it shouldn't go changing or disappearing.

EDIT::

What happens when you simply type

```
if (sqlite3_open[@"myDatabase.sqlite" UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
```

Also are you sure that the

```
NSArray * documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
databasePath = [[[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0]
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sql"] retain];
```

is actually returning where the database is?

The code I use to grab the database from the app directory where kFilename is the database file is:

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];
}
```

and then to use it I do:

```
if(sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK){
```

This works on both my iPod touch and the iPhone simulator.

EDIT2::

I've just used your above method and it seems to work here - I know it sounds stupid but have you tried rebooting? Its possible something strange is happening with the simulator

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. Copying the string that is made when finding the directory doesn't help, neither does copying the string just before I use it.